# Retrieve UnRead Emails from Gmail - JavaMail API + IMAP

Tags: gmail, jakarta-mail, imap

Now I have created a code to retrieve unread email and read its body and then we can store or do whatever we want to do.

It is completely working but the problem is that it giving me only the body for the first mail and for the second it gives the body with html tags.

I'm using JavaMail API...

How can I do??

Thanks in advance.

Best regards,
Ali

```
package pack1;
//import the necessary classes

import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.Properties;

import javax.mail.Flags;
import javax.mail.Folder;
import javax.mail.Message;
import javax.mail.MessagingException;
import javax.mail.Multipart;
import javax.mail.NoSuchProviderException;
import javax.mail.Session;
import javax.mail.Store;
import javax.mail.search.FlagTerm;

public class InboxReader {

    public static void main(String args[]) {
        Properties props = System.getProperties();
        props.setProperty("mail.store.protocol", "imaps");
            try {
                Session session = Session.getDefaultInstance(props, null);
                Store store = session.getStore("imaps");
                store.connect("imap.gmail.com", "mail", "pass");
                System.out.println(store);

                Folder inbox = store.getFolder("Inbox");
                inbox.open(Folder.READ_ONLY);
                //Message messages[] = inbox.getMessages();
                FlagTerm ft = new FlagTerm(new Flags(Flags.Flag.SEEN), false);
                Message messages[] = inbox.search(ft);

                int i =0;
                for(Message message:messages) 
                {

                     Multipart mp = (Multipart)messages[i].getContent();  
                     Object p = mp.getBodyPart(i).getContent();  
                     String q = p.toString();//object has the body content  
                     System.out.println(q);//prints the body  
                     System.out.println( messages[i].getSubject()+ " \n"+i);i++;
                }


                    } catch (NoSuchProviderException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                        System.exit(1);
                    } catch (MessagingException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                        System.exit(2);
                    } catch (IOException e) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }

    }

}
```

The output :

```
a

a 
0
<div dir="ltr">b<br>
</div>

b 
1
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 2 >= 2
    at java.util.Vector.elementAt(Unknown Source)
    at javax.mail.Multipart.getBodyPart(Multipart.java:156)
    at javax.mail.internet.MimeMultipart.getBodyPart(MimeMultipart.java:258)
    at pack1.InboxReader.main(InboxReader.java:39)
```

Comment: I wonder such a question gets +11 and not -20 (and starred with 13)

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You're using the same index to get a message from your list as to get a part from that message.  So you're fetching part 1 from message 1, part 2 from message 2, etc.  At some point, you'll hit a message N that has fewer than N parts, and you get the `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException`.

```
Multipart mp = (Multipart)messages[i].getContent();  
Object p = mp.getBodyPart(i).getContent();
```

Also, you're assuming that all your messages are multipart.  The first time you call `Message.getContent()` on a non-multipart message, you'll get a `ClassCastException` as it'll most likely be returning you a `String` instead.

```
Multipart mp = (Multipart)messages[i].getContent();
```

Similarly, you're assuming non-nested multiparts.  The first time you get a message with a top-level `multipart/mixed` containing a `multipart/alternative` as its first subpart, the call to `MimeBodyPart.getContent()` will return another `Multipart` and thus `p.toString()` will just return a Java object identifier, not the message content you want.

```
Object p = mp.getBodyPart(i).getContent();  
String q = p.toString();//object has the body content
```

To do it right, you need to walk the message structure and determine the "body" part you care about.