# Read latest thread mail using javamail

Tags: android, email, jakarta-mail, email-threading

as we know that Conversation threading is a feature used by many email clients in which the software aids the user by visually grouping messages.

i build an email client application using javamail running on Android.Guide from [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5366767/retrieve-unread-emails-from-gmail-javamail-api-imap), i have sucessfully to get unread message. 
This output is nested mail like converstation

```
  - A replay to B (latest message)
     - B reply to A
        - mail from A to B (first mail)
```

My problem is, i want to get only the latest message on this thread [A replay to B (latest message)]. How Should i do it??

Answer (score 0):

You're going to have to request enough envelope/header information to figure out which message that is, then you can fetch only the content for that message.