# IMAP client in Java: JavaMail API or Apache Commons Net?

Tags: java, email, imap, jakarta-mail, apache-commons

I have to implement an IMAP Client in Java.

Which advantages has using the Apache Commons Net library? Does it make the implementation robust and more flexible?

How do I have to handle return values, it always produces strings.

For example:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    IMAPClient client = new IMAPClient();
    client.connect(SERVER);
    client.login(USERNAME, PASSWORD);
    client.select("INBOX");
    client.fetch("1", "body[header]");
}
```

and we can direct the output to string by

```
client.addProtocolCommandListener(new PrintCommandListener(System.out, true));
```

But how can I get a list of folders as folder instances instead of pure string output?

Comment: Can't believe there hasn't been any decent answers to this question.

Comment: There is a great Apache Commons Mail API, why not use that?

Comment: This question should be closed as off-topic, being a request for  recommendation.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Short story : it depends on your real requirements.

**If your client is mainly focused on sending and reading mail**, the **JavaMail API** is a de-facto standard high-level API, and it will be much simpler to compose mail, add headers and/or attachements.

On the other hand, **if you intend to offer all the possibilities of the IMAP protocol**, the lower-level **Apache Commons Net** library will allow more detailed operations, at the cost of more boiler plate code for simple operations.

Just to complete this answer, you should not forget **Apache Commons Email**, which according to the [home page](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-email/) of the project is *built on top of the Java Mail API, which it aims to simplify*. It is much closer to JavaMail than to Commons Net.

Without knowing more of what one wants to do, it is hard to give a more precise answer...

Comment: *Apache Commons Email, built on top of the JavaMail API, which it aims to simplify* And does it actually simplify anything?

Comment: @user7610 : to be honest, I never used it and only cited what was written on project home page.

Comment: Personnal opinion : Commons mail is "simpler" in that its API tries to think of email as a user does, while the JavaMail API exposes the MIME-side of the story.
Technically, Javamail is a natural API. So "adding an attachment" in Javamail means converting from SinglePart to Multipart Mime, dealing with each part's headers, Q-Encoding this or that, and all. Commons Mail will have an `addAttachment` method that will do all that, deal with filenames, encodings...

But when it comes down to advanced configuration like, say, enabling IMAP/SSL and SMTP authentication, both are equally footed.

Comment: I have implemented both of them in a single system. In terms of implementation, both of them have pros and cons. https://github.com/r0hi7/Trashemail

Answer (score 3):

Consider looking at [Retrieve UnRead Emails from Gmail - JavaMail API + IMAP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5366767/retrieve-unread-emails-from-gmail-javamail-api-imap?rq=1)

It's coded using the JavaMail API, but in my opinion this has a much simpler interface than the Apache commons library.

If you really want to use the Apache commons library, have a look at the javadocs and see what other parameters you can pass to `.select()`.

Answer (score 3):

> how can i get list of folder as folder instances instead of pure string output?

It looks like apache IMAPClient is a low-level wrapper around the IMAP protocol, so nothing fancier than strings are provided. For an higher level API, you could look into the [JavaMail](https://java.net/projects/javamail/pages/Home) library:

```java
Session session = Session.getDefaultInstance(System.getProperties(),null);
Store store = session.getStore("imaps");
store.connect(this.host, this.userName, this.password);

// Get default folder
Folder folder = store.getDefaultFolder();

// Get any folder by name
Folder[] folderList = folder.list();
```

Answer (score 3):

There are modern alternatives I recently checked out:

1. [Yahoo IMAP client](https://github.com/yahoo/imapnio): supports async IO using Java Futures, but is low level and maybe too complicated for simple use cases like checking for new mail.
2. [Email4J](https://github.com/jhult/email4j): easy-to-use, high-level API that uses Java Mail beneath, but not in Maven central yet and a large PR is still open (I am using the fork)

For local testing, I am using the lightweight [docker-imap-devel](https://github.com/antespi/docker-imap-devel) docker image.

A good introduction, looking behind the scenes of the IMAP protocol (helpful for debugging), can be found at [IMAP 101: Manual IMAP Sessions](https://www.atmail.com/blog/imap-101-manual-imap-sessions/).

*Update*: In the end, it was the easiest to go with good old [javax.mail.imap API](https://javaee.github.io/javamail/docs/api/com/sun/mail/imap/package-summary.html) and `Folder.open()` which worked out of the box, should have checked that earlier…
There's also an experimental `IdleManager` that can be used to watch a mailbox for new messages with a supplied `ExecutorService`.